# InitalValues don't change even though the state they are set to does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, semantic-ui, redux-form

I have a Semantic-UI modal that contains a redux-form as it's content. When opening the modal, I pass the form to it's content prop. The form element has an `initialValues` prop set to a prop mapped to state.

```
                <FormModal
                    handleSubmit={ this.sortSubmit }
                    size='small'
                    formName='sortForm'
                    header='Sort'
                    headerIcon='sort'
                    content={
                        <SortForm table={ this.props.table } initialValues={ { orderBy: this.props.search.orderBy, orderDirection: this.props.search.orderDirection } } />
                    }
                    trigger={
                        <Button icon floated='right' size="mini">
                            <Icon name='sort' />
                        </Button>
                    }
                />
```

I then change this.props.search.orderBy by changing the redux state. Everything in the app updates to reflect the change, except this redux-form's initialValues, which should change when the state changes. I open the modal again, and the fields are reset to the old initialValues instead of the newly set values.

Any ideas why this would happen?

On a possibly related note, re-rendering the modal JSX does not seem to close the modal. Since the modal's initial state is closed, I would have assumed a re-render of it would re-close it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `enableReinitialize={true}` to your form.

Because `enableReinitialize` defaults to false. In this case, `initialValues` is only applied at `componentWillMount`.

Here is the part of doc about `enableReinitialize`:

> When set to true, the form will reinitialize every time the
>   initialValues prop changes. Defaults to false. If the
>   keepDirtyOnReinitialize option is also set, the form will retain the
>   value of dirty fields when reinitializing.

For more info, please read [reduxForm](http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/)

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately I already tried that, as well as the keepDirtyOnReinitialize prop. neither seems to have an effect. I don't think the methods mentioned in the docs work for props passed in from the Form's JSX tag for some reason. I eventually solved the problem by mapping the state to props directly with `connect` inside the Form component, and it finally started working. this is a bummer though because I would like to be able to control the initial values from outside the form component. may just be broken.

Comment: You are right. `initialValues` is supposed to be passed to `reduxForm` not the actual form... as well as `enableReinitialize`.

Comment: The `SortForm` is a bit different from what I think it does.

Comment: @dqhendricks, could you please update your post with the solution you came up with? Been stuck on this one for awhile. Using react-table, and redux-form. On react-table sort, the initialValues for the form do not change.

Comment: @NathanCH I think I had eventually discovered that anything passed via prop will not update when it changes. I had to find a different way to get the data to the object.